# Docker containers still running while PC is hibernating?

Tags: windows, docker

New to Docker here.

So yesterday I've created a container, then put the PC to hibernate and today it shows the container is created and **running since 21 hours**. Does the container still runs while the PC is hibernating?

As far as I know, hibernating saves the current state and then restores it, but it shouldn't be running processes(containers)?

[image: CMD Output]

Comment: The "up 21 hours" is just a calculation of `(the time now) - (the time when the container started)`. It doesn't reflect actual run time.

Comment: No, it's not running during hibernation. @larsks is right.